# Why is SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT always getting set to True?

Tags: django, heroku, development-environment, django-settings

I currently have a local `.env` file which contains parameters for my local environment. I have a Django App hosted on Heroku where I assign my config variables. I figured using `python-decouple`'s .env file to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False` and then in my `settings.py` use `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = config('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT')` would work. However, no matter the case, if Django sees `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` ANYWHERE, it tries to load as HTTPS and my god is it frustrating.

Comment: How do you know that it is because of `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` and not something else such as HSTS?

Comment: I don't know. :(

Comment: Use an SSL analyzer (such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to make sure that it is not HSTS first.

Comment: Okay will check this out tomorrow. Thank you for help. Will respond after.

Comment: Everything passed with grade A from that link.

Comment: I'm sure it passed; I was suggesting that you should check if HSTS is enabled.

Comment: From the analysis: 
`Strict Transport Security (HSTS) No`
`HSTS Preloading Not in: Chrome  Edge  Firefox  IE`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the `cast=bool` setting (e.g. `config('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT', cast=bool)`)

https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple/#why-not-just-use-environment-variables